# How to calculate a daily running total from an aliased column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing a query to return a table of booking data for an event. I've used a `SUM` aggregate to group the number of daily bookings. I'd now like to create a column with a cumulative running total.

I can't make my query work because (I'm presuming) it doesn't like the aliased column title being included in the aggregate function.

Please can anyone advise me on the best approach to make this work?

```
SELECT
    'Recruitment Event' Event,
    CAST(ep.CREATIONDATE AS date) AS 'Date of Booking',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN ep.CREATIONDATE IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) 'Total Bookings',
    (SELECT
        SUM('Total Bookings')
    FROM EVENTPLACE AS ep
    WHERE CAST(ep.CREATIONDATE AS date) <= CAST(ep.CREATIONDATE AS date))
    'Running Total'
FROM EVENTPLACE AS ep
LEFT JOIN EVENTMODULE AS em
    ON em.EVENTMODULENO = ep.EVENTMODULENO
WHERE em.EVENTMODULENO = '11111111-ABCD-1234-1234-1010101010'
GROUP BY CAST(ep.CREATIONDATE AS date)
ORDER BY CAST(ep.CREATIONDATE AS date) DESC
```

Comment: Define "can't make my query work".

Comment: Apologies, should have been more specific. It throws the following error: Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: You're using the same alias inside and outside of the subquery. Change one of them to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT  
    [Event]             = 'Recruitment Event' ,
    [Date of Booking]   = CAST(ep.CREATIONDATE AS DATE),
    [Total Bookings]    = COUNT(ep.CREATIONDATE),
    [Running Total]     = SUM(COUNT(ep.CREATIONDATE)) OVER (ORDER BY CAST(ep.CREATIONDATE AS DATE) DESC)
FROM    
    EVENTPLACE AS ep
WHERE   
    EXISTS (SELECT 
                * 
            FROM 
                EVENTMODULE em 
            WHERE 
                em.EVENTMODULENO = ep.EVENTMODULENO 
                AND em.EVENTMODULENO = '11111111-ABCD-1234-1234-1010101010')
GROUP BY 
    CAST(ep.CREATIONDATE AS DATE)
ORDER BY 
    CAST(ep.CREATIONDATE AS DATE) DESC
```

`COUNT(ep.CREATIONDATE)` will ignore null values with the same result as your `SUM(CASE)`

You dont really have to use `EXISTS`, but you should probably change your `LEFT JOIN` to a `JOIN` since you're using the `em.EVENTMODULENO` in the `WHERE` statement

`SUM(COUNT(ep.CREATIONDATE)) OVER ()` will give you running total of the count. You use `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` to determine the order of the `SUM`.  Since you're ordering by `CAST(ep.CREATIONDATE AS DATE) DESC` you can just use that in the `OVER()`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because of these lines..

```
SUM (case when ep.CREATIONDATE IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) 'Total Bookings',
(SELECT SUM ('Total Bookings') FROM EVENTPLACE
```

You are trying to select alias which was defined in same phase and you are passing it as string .your query wont work unless you correlate it with main table which you are not doing..

Below query works from SQLServer 2012

```
;with cte
as
(
SELECT 'Recruitment Event' Event,
cast(ep.CREATIONDATE as date) as 'Date of Booking',
SUM (case when ep.CREATIONDATE IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) 'Total Bookings',
FROM EVENTPLACE as ep
LEFT JOIN EVENTMODULE as em ON em.EVENTMODULENO=ep.EVENTMODULENO
WHERE em.EVENTMODULENO = '11111111-ABCD-1234-1234-1010101010'
GROUP BY cast(ep.CREATIONDATE as date)
)
select *,
sum([Total Bookings]) 
over (order by [Date of Booking] ROWS UNBOUNDED  ECEDING ) as   'Runningtotal'
from 
 cte
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This works for me. I've not used common table expressions before, so I'm wondering if it's possible to nest them so that e.g. I can add additional columns to the above table, and then another running total after these?

Comment: yes . when you alias something  and use that in CTE,you can just query like normal tables

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is a SUM() function in your select statement, but not all the other columns are included in your group by clause.

The solution is that add an OVER(ORDER BY ...) clause after your SUM function to calculate the running total.

```
SELECT
    'Recruitment Event' Event,
    CAST(ep.CREATIONDATE AS date) AS 'Date of Booking',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN ep.CREATIONDATE IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END)OVER(ORDER BY CAST(ep.CREATIONDATE AS date) DESC)  'Running Total',
FROM EVENTPLACE AS ep
LEFT JOIN EVENTMODULE AS em
    ON em.EVENTMODULENO = ep.EVENTMODULENO
WHERE em.EVENTMODULENO = '11111111-ABCD-1234-1234-1010101010'
CAST(ep.CREATIONDATE AS date) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried this but it gives me a running count of the number of returned row - it doesn't give me a running summed total of the aliased column I'm afraid.